# Complex Float calculations from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

```
Machine1 | Machine2 | Machine3 | Shift |
   abc   |    pqr   |  xyz     |First  |

Machine |SetupTime |OpnTime |
  abc   |   80     |   30   |
  pqr   |   60     |   40   |
  xyz   |   40     |   50   |

Shift | Time |
First |  440 |
```

I want the total addition of OpnTime for all machines divides with shift Time which substracts with
addition of setupTime as

```
((OpnTime+Opntime+OpnTime)/Time-(SetupTime+SetupTime+SetupTime))*100

((30+40+50)/440-(80+60+40))*100

(120/440-180)*100

(120/260)*100

(0.46)*100

46%
```

Could you please help me how to simply solve this complex calculations

Comment: Unless your question relates to both the [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server-2008] products, you've got too many tags on your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what we see here. One table with four columns (machine1/2/3, shift)? And it always only contains one record? One table with always one record per machine holding the two times? A third table with one record per shift holding the shift time? Yes?

Comment: yes. i just need a query to get above calculations that i have shown which gets  an output of 46%.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT (SUM(TAB2.OpnTime) / (TAB3.Time - (SUM(TAB2.SetupTime))) * 100
FROM TAB2, TAB3;
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said thet all my assumptions in your comments section were right, here is a solution:

```
select 
  (m1.opntime + m2.opntime + m3.opntime) / 
  (s.time - m1.setuptime - m2.setuptime - m3.setuptime) * 100
from t
join m1 on m1.machine = t.machine1
join m2 on m2.machine = t.machine2
join m3 on m3.machine = t.machine3
join s on s.shift = t.shift;
```

It is just a matter of setting parentheses correctly. As there is only one record in t and only one record per machine in m and only one record per shift in s, this is the easiest and fasted approach. No need for aggregation for example. (Given that, I wonder what your actual problem was. It seems so easy. Where did you fail?)

EDIT: If your columns aren't decimals, but integers, then you must convert to decimal. In integer math 120 / 260 is 0. In decimal math 120 / 260 is 0.4615...

```
select 
  cast(m1.opntime + m2.opntime + m3.opntime as decimal) / 
  cast(s.time - m1.setuptime - m2.setuptime - m3.setuptime as decimal) * 100
from t
join m1 on m1.machine = t.machine1
join m2 on m2.machine = t.machine2
join m3 on m3.machine = t.machine3
join s on s.shift = t.shift;
```